# Why would I want to use one way of closing a form over another?

Tags: c#, winforms

When closing a windows form, I can use:

- `this.Close();`
- `Application.Exit();`
- `Environment.Exit(0);`
  `Environment.Exit(1);`
  `Environment.Exit(-1);`

What are the differences between these options? Why would I want to use one over the other?

Comment: Have you read the MSDN notes on [`Form.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx), [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)?

Comment: Check this http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

Comment: The first one is to close the form. The rest are to end your application. Catch them here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584483/whats-the-difference-between-these-methods-for-closing-my-application?rq=1

Comment: -1 as this question does not show any research effort into the documentation of each individual method.

Answer (score 1):

Here are descriptions of these straight from MSDN (and a couple extra comments):

[this/Form.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx)(), called from within the context of a `Form` instance.

> Closes the form.

Note that this would only exit the application if it was the last form remaining open within your application, and that there are no other foreground threads running.

[Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx)()

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

A method that can be called from anywhere within your application which will terminate all message pumps on foreground threads. Again, this will not exit other foreground threads that do not have a message loop running, and so is not guaranteed to close the application.

[Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)() with an optional exit code.

> Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code.

This attempts to terminate the process by ending all threads running within, and will then return the exit code to the operating system. This could, for example, be used to return a failure status to a batch file that spawned the application in the first place. This is generally used only when a process is needed to be terminated forcefully, and once again may not close the application immediately if it must wait for threads to end.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Application.Run(mainForm)` standard application message loop begins running on current thread, and specified form will be shown. Also this method adds an event handler to the mainForm for the `Closed` event. The event handler calls `ExitThread` to clean up the application. `ExitThread` exits the message loop on the current thread and closes all windows on the thread. That what happens when you call [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) on main form.

[`Application.Exit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) just raises `FormClosing` event for every form represented by the `OpenForms` property. You can cancel this event in any form. In this case Exit returns without further action. Otherwise, a `FormClosed` event is raised for every open form, then all running message loops and forms are closed.

[`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) terminates process (brutally) and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code. If you pass non-zero code, that will indicate that error occurred in your application. This is the fastest way to kill application.